# Boiler won't fire unless the water heater triggers the power exhaust fan

Tags: boiler

I have a PB MI-03-STDG-WPC boiler running on natural gas, and it's connected to a powered exhaust vent that it shares with my water heater (a separate unit).  If it matters, the house is heated by forced hot water through baseboard units throughout my house.

My thermostats are set to 62F, but the two zones in my house are currently at ~55F (up from 51-52F this morning).  It's chilly in here, so I've been poking around on and off all day to try and figure it out.  Cash flow is a bit of an issue at the moment (one of my contracts is late on paying me), so I'd like to fix this myself if possible (and safe, of course).

It appears as though the boiler won't trigger the power exhaust vent.  If I run the hot water from a sink or the shower, the water heater will fire up and turn on the exhaust vent.  When this happens, the boiler comes to life and fires up.  But when the water heater is done, the power exhaust fan turns off, and the boiler goes back to its idle mode with just the pilot light lit.

At 17 years old, perhaps it's coming to be time to replace the furnace with a newer, more efficient one, but I'd like to get my finances in order first, or at least have some time to research what I need to have done (and who I should have do it).

So any suggestions on what to check next would be greatly appreciated.  It would be awesome if I could just replace a switching unit somewhere and get a little more life out of this boiler.  But if nothing else, it would nice to not have to bundle up inside all the time for the next couple of months before the weather outside warms up.

Thanks for any help/advice anyone can give.

EDIT: it's very faded, but here's the wiring diagram for the Honeywell L8148E control(?) unit on the side of the boiler.
[image: Honeywell L8148E wiring]

EDIT2:  Looks like the power vent is controlled by a Field Controls CK-92FV.

Next morning update:  on a whim, I decided to set both of my Nest thermostats to OFF and then back to HEAT before I went to bed last night.  And...my house was being heated as normal this morning.  I'm going to keep an eye on things for a couple of days and if that was it, then I'll mark this as answered.

Comment: Can you provide pictures of the electrical diagrams for the water heater and the boiler?  Did this problem just start happening?

Comment: @JACK It is a new problem, at least to this extent.  Once in a while (over the past year or so), the boiler would behave oddly for a day or so (not firing up as much as it should have), but this is the first time that it's basically gone all day without working.  I'll have to see what I can dig up for wiring diagrams for the Honeywell controller on the side of the boiler and the front of my water heater. For what it's worth, the two only meet up at the power exhaust vent.

Comment: what else s connected to the L8148E  how is the exhaust fan connected?